# Dynamic element in system.xml field

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system.xml, magento2.3.3

I have a list of elements printed with a field `type='checkboxes'` but when I try to save only one of the results saved.

As a solution to this problem, we tried to print each element with a checkbox and so Magento saves it in the database as a single row.

Right now we have an array with the data and what we need is to loop through them as a field in the `system.xml`

The `system.xml` is like that:

```
 <field id="cmspage" translate="label comment" type="checkboxes" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Lista pagine</label>
        <source_model>[vendor]\PersonalMenu\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Cms\Cms</source_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
 </field>
```

The `source_model` give in the output the array

Is the `backend_model` the file where we can set the loop?

Or are there some other ways to customize a module settings page with all the elements dynamically showed?

P.S. sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Is the config type "checkboxes" a custom type for system.xml you implemented ? because i don't think there is a type in vanilla Magento2 which is called like this.

You may want to utilize a frontend_model to render the checkboxes in your store configuration.
Here is a guide how to set up a frontend_model for a store configuration field:
https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-backend-configuration-frontend-model-part-33/